# Regex: select the html class that does not contain the word

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to find all the files in which there is no class like  that contains the word "neculaifantaru"

I have these 2 html same classes:

```
<p class="mb-40px">I must go home, but I don't know the road.</p>
<p class="mb-40px">I love myself , because I love nature.</p>
<p class="mb-40px">Cercetare estetică, care poartă <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/qualities-of-a-leader.html" class="color-bebe" target="_new">lumina artei</a> sinestezice</p>
```

**The output must be:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">I must go home, but I don't know the road.</p>
<p class="mb-40px">I love myself , because I love nature.</p>
```

**My regex is not very good:**

```
(?-si:<p class="mb-40px">|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!</p>).)*?\K(?-si:?!neculaifantanaru)
```

**In Python it is easy. But I need a regex to do the same:**

```
import os
import re

# Calea către directorul în care doriți să căutați
cale_director = 'g:/1/GATA ro'

# Parcurgeți toate fișierele din director
for nume_fisier in os.listdir(cale_director):
    cale_fisier = os.path.join(cale_director, nume_fisier)

    # Deschideți fiecare fișier și citiți conținutul acestuia
    with open(cale_fisier, 'r') as fisier:
        continut = fisier.read()

        # Căutați toate tagurile <p class="mb-40px">.*?</p>
        taguri_p = re.findall(r'<p class="mb-40px">(.*?)</p>', continut, re.DOTALL)

        # Verificați dacă există vreun tag care conține cuvântul "neculaifantanaru"
        tag_cu_neculaifantanaru = any('neculaifantanaru' in tag for tag in taguri_p)

        # Verificați dacă nu există niciun tag care să conțină cuvântul "neculaifantanaru"
        if not tag_cu_neculaifantanaru:
            print(f'Fișierul "{nume_fisier}" nu conține niciun tag <p class="mb-40px"> care să includă cuvântul "neculaifantanaru".')
```

Comment: If you are familiar with Python I suggest an installation of the Notepad++ **Python Script** plugin.

Comment: yes, I have installed notepad++. And I need a regex for Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

**FIND:** `(?s)\A(?!.*(neculaifantanaru).*$)`

...If it is not necessary to integrate between `<p class="mb-40px">` and `</p>`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="mb-40px">(?:(?!</p>).)*neculaifantanaru.*?</p>\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">     # literally
(?:                     # non capture group
    (?!                     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't </p> after
        </p>                    # literally
    )                       # end lookahead
    .                       # any character
)*                      # end group, may appear 0 or more times
neculaifantanaru        # literally
.*?                     # 0 or more any character, not greedy
</p>                    # literally
\R?                     # optional line break
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: the opposite was needed. I had to find all the lines, except those containing "neculaifantaru"

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: The result of my proposition is exactly what you expected in your question. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/180121). What are you trying to do?